# Why does same code outputs different values?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools, python-zip

```
import itertools
def f(x,y,z,w):
    return ((x and y) or (y and z)) == ((not(x) or w) and (not(w) or z))

for p in itertools.permutations("xyzw"):
    ans = []
    t = [(0,1,1,1), (0,1,0,0), (0,1,0,1)]
    for r in t:
        #ans.append(f(*r))
        #ans.append(f(**dict(zip(p,r))))
    if ans == [1,1,1]:
        print(*p)
        break
```

If I uncomment `ans.append(f(*r))` it outputs nothing, but if I uncomment `ans.append(f(**dict(zip(p,r))))` it outputs my answer. Why does that happen?

I'm expecting the same output, but there are different arrays after `dict(zip)` values.

Comment: Add *print(f(*r))* and you'll see why

Comment: You aren't using `p` at all if you do `ans.append(f(*r))`, so how is it "the same code" as `ans.append(f(**dict(zip(p,r))))`?

Comment: i dont understand why *r and **dict(zip(p,r)) sometimes output different values

Comment: im making keys for dict from `r`, so i think that `r` and keys from dict should be equal, but they arent

Comment: No, you're making keys for dict from `p`, not `r`. `r` is where you draw values from.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting different outputs is because the two function calls are not passing the same values to the arguments of `f()`:

- `f(*r)` passes positional arguments from the array of tuples `t`, with the first value being assigned to `x`, the second to `y`, the third to `z`, and the fourth to `w`. So no matter what `p` is, you're getting `ans = [f(0,1,1,1), f(0,1,0,0), f(0,1,0,1)]`.
- `f(**dict(zip(p,r)))` passes keyword arguments with the expected keys `x`, `y`, `z`, `w`, but the order in which the values from the array of tuples `t` are assigned to `x`, `y`, `z`, `w` is determined by the current permutation `p`. For example, on the first iteration of the for loop, with `p = ('x', 'y', 'z', 'w')`, you'll get `ans = [f(x=0,y=1,z=1,=w=1), ...]` equivalent to `[f(0,1,1,1), ...]` as in the positional argument version above, but on a later iteration, with `p = ('y', 'x', 'z', 'w')` you'll get `ans = [f(y=0,x=1,z=1,w=1), ...]` (**note the inverted assignments of values to x and y**) which is equivalent to `ans = [f(1,0,1,1), ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `f(*r)` is similar to calling `f(**dict(zip(['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'], r)))` [or `f(**dict(zip('xyzw',r)))`, or `f(x=r[0], y=r[1], z=r[2], w=r[3])`], but `p` has the argument names shifted around every loop; so you need to `zip` with `p`, otherwise you'll be doing the same thing for every `p`, and the outermost loop becomes entirely redundant.